# Why am I unable to import @rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, web3js, cryptocurrency

I am trying to integrate `rainbowkit` and `wagmi` into an existing website that currently uses `web3`. It works when I comment out the styles import but it just looks really ugly. I have made sure npm is latest version and so are rainbowkit and wagmi.

My import statement:

`import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css'`

result:

Failed to compile.

```
./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css' in '/home/apollo/manifest-github/physical-claim-frontend/src'
```

Comment: This issue was resolved in rainbow kit 0.6.1

https://github.com/rainbow-me/rainbowkit/releases/tag/%40rainbow-me%2Frainbowkit%400.6.1

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue as well.

I replaced the import with

```
import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/index.css';
```

which is the non aliased path

seems to be compiling fine now!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by replacing `import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css'` to `import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/index.css'`;